# Does Catfolk's ancestry feat Lucky Break work with the Grapple action?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, grapple, races

For reference:

- [Grapple action](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=35)
- [Lucky Break feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2320)

I argue that when grappling with the Lucky Break feat, you are able to reroll the Grapple attack action (when failing or critical failing), because the Grapple action clearly states to

> Attempt an Athletics check against the target's Fortitude DC.

My own counter-argument would be that Lucky Break says

> You can trigger Cat's Luck when you fail or critically fail on an Athletics or Acrobatics **skill check** [...]

whereas Grapple action says

> Attempt an Athletics **check** [...]

But this counter-argument would require *Athletics skill check* to be something different  from *Athletics check* and i can't find anything in the Core Rulebook differentiating these wordings. Alternatively, is there something specifically written about using skills in combat like Grapple and Disarm (Attack trait), or Feint and Demoralize (no Attack trait)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

From Skill Checks and Skill DC's

> Pathfinder has a variety of skills, from Athletics to Medicine to Occultism. Each grants you a set of related actions that rely on you rolling a skill check.

And Grapple is an *action related to* Athletics. Specifically, an **[Athletics Untrained Action](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=3)** Gaining the Attack Trait (to count MAP) does not make it *not* a Skill Action.

It may help to note the description of [Attack Rolls](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=320)

> When you use a **Strike action or make a spell attack**, you attempt a check called an attack roll. Attack rolls take a variety of forms and are often highly variable based on the weapon you are using for the attack, but there are **three main types**: melee attack rolls, ranged attack rolls, and spell attack rolls.

Similarly, Feint is a Deception skill action and Demoralize is an Intimidate skill action. Anything that applies to skills applies to these. It would seem your confusion comes from expecting a separation of combat-focused skill actions from others, but Pathfinder 2e makes no such distinction.